# Наблюдённый - нормальное слово?

Tags: грамматика

Наблюдённый (параметр) - нормальное слово?

Меня за него отругали. В словарях есть, но может, со стилем что-то не то?

Comment: Если отругали - вернитесь и спросите а как правильно. А то мы тут насоветуем, а им вдруг не понравится.

Comment: Приветствую! У нас тут новые веенья... Разные авторы насоветовать обещают.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А кто отругал-то? Если редактор, то спорить бесполезно.

Слово это сильно не любят новоявленные пуристы, я сталкивался.
Причем чем дальше человек от науки, тем более яростно на слово нападает.

Причина - в кажущемся неблагозвучии. И надо признать, слово реально устаревает в обычной речи. В книжной, научной - сидит довольно прочно.

Если текст научный, то я бы придираться не стал.
И вообще, что за постановка вопроса, "отругали"?

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. "Отругали" - ну это в порядке дискуссии.

Answer (score 2):

В Нацкорпусе 5 примеров применения слова "наблюдённый" в книжной или научной речи (последний  – в 1932 году):

В основе этого поверья лежит **наблюдённый** факт, что папоротник никогда не цветет, что у него нет цветов, как у других растений. [К. А. Тимирязев и др. Жизнь растения (1878)]

Зеленый луч, **наблюдённый** древними египтянами на горизонте после заката солнца, сделавшийся для них цветом траура, как отсвет из подземного царства смерти, ― этот зеленый, наблюдаемый поныне, луч и является дополнительным к красноте солнца, исчезнувшего за горизонтом. [К. С. Петров-Водкин. Моя повесть. Часть 2. Пространство Эвклида (1932)]

Answer (score -1):

Нормальное, но крайне редко употребляемое. Как и глагол *наблюсти,* который образовал нам это страдательное причастие прошедшего времени.

В словарях есть, а Ушаков и [пример приводит](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/866146):

> Явления, наблюдённые на солнце астрономами.

Наблюдён, наблюдена, наблюдено...

Нет, всё же ч**у**дные формы слова мы с Вами наблюли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Я наблюла, а ты наблюл?"

Ой, ещё пример - из недавняго прошлаго ©:

> «Явления Венеры на Солнце, наблюдённое в Санктпетербургской
> императорской Академии Наук майя 26 дня 1761 года». Ломоносов М.В.

А если кто-нито жалуется на стиль, то помета "устар." отсутствует как класс.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте объяснения в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. У многих пользователей с плохим доступом к Сети отключены картинки; Более того, ваш ответ практически невозможно найти через поисковик: основная идея сайта вопросов и ответов в многократном использование решений, которая сводится на нет в случае использования изображений.

Comment: *Нет, всё же чудные формы слова мы с Вами наблюли:* - мне слово знакомо, если вы что-то и наблюли, то без меня.

Comment: IrinaGL, я наблюла Ваш комментарий, с ошибкой. Больше прошу меня не беспокоить и обещаю впредь не беспокоить Вас ответами.

Comment: Nicolas, я учла пожелание не вставлять картинки; у меня ссылка на словарь Ушакова кликабельна, а пример из него оформлен как цитата. То, что в данном ответе - картинка, имеет лишь косвенное отношение к вопросу, на который, дважды сминусованный, дан исчерпывающий ответ: словарями фиксируется (плюс пример-цитата), стилистическая помета "устар." отсутствует. Это всё. А картинка - личное наблюдение, желание поделиться обнаруженными словоформами.

Comment: *я наблюла Ваш комментарий* - вот это уже лучше. ))) А в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ирина, если Вас опять станут обижать, скажите, что вы позовёте констебля ))